# How do I automatically update table columns while importing data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `my_table` with layout as follows (sample rows):

```
id    start                 end
1     2010-05-29 11:22:00   2010-06-06 13:45:59
2     2010-04-03 01:15:00   2010-07-21 14:30:59
3     2010-05-02 16:12:00   2010-11-01 15:12:59
```

Column `id` is of data type `integer` while `start` and `end` columns are in `character varying(20)`. I have a database `my_db` in PostgreSQL 9.5 (x64) on Windows 7 (x64) based machine. I want to change the data type of `start` and end `columns` to `timestamp without time zone`. This can be achieved easily with Postgres command:

```
Alter table my_table alter column start type timestamp without time zone using start::timestamp without time zone
```

However, I would like to update the data type of these columns while importing data into `my_db`. I was wondering that in PostgreSQL is it possible to update column data types when data is imported (for example, when data is imported via PostGIS shapefile/DBF loader or QGIS DB Manager then PostgreSQL detects these data types automatically and changes them to the desired ones). If yes, then can someone suggest me how do I automate such process?

Comment: you dont update column data type for each row - you just alter table once

Comment: Just edited the question. Instead of doing it everytime I upload table, is it not possible that PostgreSQL detects these column types automatically and changes them to the desired ones?

Comment: no, not really - you create table specification yourself

Comment: I am quite puzzled! Yes, it is true we import the data and can alter the column types to the desired ones. But, instead of doing it everytime I import data (CSV for example), it would have been desired scenario that PostgreSQL detects the data types and update them to the required ones so if I forgot to change the data type, my query will still rock.

Comment: Pg would need to know the datatype before the import. You can set columns to all be text so they will accept more variants and the do some validation after import.

Comment: Since you already know the column datatypes (int,timestamp,timestamp}, why don't you define them that way *before* importing the CSV?

Comment: @joop: I could do this as well. But, when it comes to working with large number of records in CSVs, it ain't so handy. So, I wondered whether is it possible that PostgreSQL automatically handles the data everytime I import the stuff into it! But seems no success :(

Comment: {import+convert} will always be more costly than {import} Large_number_of_CSVs is irrelevant here.